# Are there any circumstances under which a council tenancy of a council flat in a council estate can be sublet?

Tags: england-and-wales

Generally the answer is a clear no, but what exceptions are there to this, if any?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The Citizens Advice Bureau states in [Rights of tenants to sublet their home](https://www.citizensadvice.org.uk/housing/renting-a-home/subletting-and-lodging/subletting/rights-of-tenants-to-sublet-their-home/)

> **Rights of secure and flexible tenants to sublet**
>
> Most local authority tenants are secure tenants. You are also likely to be a secure tenant if your landlord is a housing association and your tenancy started before 15 January 1989.
>
> Most secure tenancies don’t have an end date. If your tenancy has an end date and you rent from the local authority, your tenancy is a ‘flexible tenancy’. Flexible tenancies are a type of secure tenancy.
>
> **What rights do secure and flexible tenants have to sublet?**
>
> You can sublet part of your home with your landlord's written permission. If you sublet part of your home without permission, you are in breach of your tenancy agreement.
>
> Your landlord can't unreasonably withhold their consent to a request to sublet part of your home. Also, your landlord can't attach conditions if they allow you to sublet.
>
> If your landlord refuses your request to sublet part of your home, they must give you their reasons why.

And then, crucially

> You can't lawfully sublet **all** of your home. If you do, you lose your status as a secure tenant and your landlord can evict you.

For more detail about types of tenancy, please see that page.

Comment: Also see under [Secure tenancy](https://www.gov.uk/council-housing/types-of-tenancy): You can rent out rooms - but you cannot sub-let the whole property